Avatar failed to start. Error: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded
// utilty.js
export const fetchIceCredentials = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://westus2.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/avatar/relay/token/v1', {
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': cogSvcSubKey
            }
        });
        const { Username: iceUsername, Password: iceCredential } = response.data;
        if (!iceUsername || !iceCredential) {
            throw new Error('ICE credentials are missing');
        }
        if (iceUsername && iceCredential) {
            // Check base64 encoding
            if (!isValidBase64(iceCredential)) {
                console.error('ICE credential is not a valid base64 string:', iceCredential);
                console.error('ICE UserName is not a valid base64 string:', iceUsername);
                throw new Error('Invalid base64 encoding');
            } else{ 
                console.log('iceCredential is valid')
            return { iceUsername, iceCredential };
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('Invalid credentials format');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching ICE credentials:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export function isValidBase64(str) {
    const base64Regex = /^([A-Za-z0-9+/=]+)$/;

    if (!base64Regex.test(str)) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        const decodedStr = atob(str);
        return btoa(decodedStr) === str;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}


export const createWebRTCConnection = (iceServerUrl, iceServerUsername, iceServerCredential) => {
    try {
        const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [{
                urls: [iceServerUrl],
                username: iceServerUsername,
                credential: iceServerCredential
            }]
        });
        return peerConnection;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating WebRTC connection: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
 
export const createAvatarSynthesizer = () => {
    try {
        console.log("Initializing Speech SDK with:", cogSvcSubKey, cogSvcRegion, voiceName);
        const speechSynthesisConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(cogSvcSubKey, cogSvcRegion);
        speechSynthesisConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = voiceName;
 
        const videoFormat = new SpeechSDK.AvatarVideoFormat();
 
        const videoCropTopLeftX = 600;
        const videoCropBottomRightX = 1320;
        videoFormat.setCropRange(new SpeechSDK.Coordinate(videoCropTopLeftX, 50), new SpeechSDK.Coordinate(videoCropBottomRightX, 1080));
 
        console.log("Avatar configuration:", avatarCharacter, avatarStyle, avatarBackgroundColor);
        const avatarConfig = new SpeechSDK.AvatarConfig(avatarCharacter, avatarStyle, videoFormat);
        avatarConfig.backgroundColor = avatarBackgroundColor;
 
        const avatarSynthesizer = new SpeechSDK.AvatarSynthesizer(speechSynthesisConfig, avatarConfig);
 
        avatarSynthesizer.avatarEventReceived = (s, e) => {
            const offsetMessage = e.offset === 0 ? "" : `, offset from session start: ${e.offset / 10000}ms.`;
            console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] Event received: ${e.description}${offsetMessage}`);
        };
 
        return avatarSynthesizer;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating Avatar Synthesizer: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

// App.jsx--Part of React code
// Fetch ICE credentials
        const { iceUsername, iceCredential } = await fetchIceCredentials();
        const iceUrl = avatarAppConfig.iceUrl;
        let peerConnection = createWebRTCConnection(iceUrl, iceUsername, iceCredential);
        peerConnection.ontrack = handleOnTrack;
        peerConnection.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'sendrecv' });
        peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'sendrecv' });
        console.log("WebRTC connection created.");

        let synthesizer = createAvatarSynthesizer();
        setAvatarSynthesizer(synthesizer);
        peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {
            console.log("WebRTC status: " + peerConnection.iceConnectionState);

            if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'connected') {
                console.log("Connected to Azure Avatar service");
            } else if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'failed') {
                console.log("Azure Avatar service Disconnected");
            }
        };
        synthesizer.startAvatarAsync(peerConnection).then((r) => {
            console.log("[" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "] Avatar started.");
            
        }).catch(async (error) => {
                console.error("[" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "] Avatar failed to start. Error: " + error);

            }
        );
    };

I am getting error as
Avatar failed to start. Error: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

When attempting to access the webpage, I consistently encounter an error. Refreshing the page does not resolve the issue, as the error persists. Occasionally, if I wait for 30-40 seconds before refreshing, the page loads correctly and the avatar appears. However, this solution is unreliable, as the error occurs more often than not. I am unable to determine the underlying cause of this problem and require assistance in diagnosing and resolving it.

This question is similar to: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Avatar failed to start. Error: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute ‘atob’ on ‘Window’: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

The credentials you receive from the API are indeed valid base64 strings. First log the response to see what you’re getting.

The current validation function may not be robust enough Improve the base64 validation function.

        // Check base64 encoding
        if (!isValidBase64(iceCredential)) {
            console.error('ICE credential is not a valid base64 string:', iceCredential);
            throw new Error('Invalid base64 encoding');
        } else if (!isValidBase64(iceUsername)) {
            console.error('ICE Username is not a valid base64 string:', iceUsername);
            throw new Error('Invalid base64 encoding');
        } else {
            console.log('ICE credentials are valid');
            return { iceUsername, iceCredential };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching ICE credentials:', error);
        throw error;
    }

App.jsx:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchIceCredentials, createWebRTCConnection, createAvatarSynthesizer } from './utility';

const App = () => {
    const [avatarSynthesizer, setAvatarSynthesizer] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const initialize = async () => {
            try {
                const { iceUsername, iceCredential } = await fetchIceCredentials();
                const iceUrl = avatarAppConfig.iceUrl;

                let peerConnection = createWebRTCConnection(iceUrl, iceUsername, iceCredential);
                peerConnection.ontrack = handleOnTrack;
                peerConnection.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'sendrecv' });
                peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'sendrecv' });
                console.log("WebRTC connection created.");

                let synthesizer = createAvatarSynthesizer();
                setAvatarSynthesizer(synthesizer);
                
                peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {
                    console.log("WebRTC status: " + peerConnection.iceConnectionState);

                    if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'connected') {
                        console.log("Connected to Azure Avatar service");
                    } else if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'failed') {
                        console.log("Azure Avatar service Disconnected");
                    }
                };
                
                synthesizer.startAvatarAsync(peerConnection).then((r) => {
                    console.log("[" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "] Avatar started.");
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("[" + (new Date()).toISOString() + "] Avatar failed to start. Error: " + error);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error during initialization:", error);
            }
        };

        initialize();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Your UI code here */}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;


Sometimes, intermittent network issues can cause problems. Maintain a stable network connection.

Result:
[INFO] Initializing Speech SDK with: YOUR_COG_SVC_SUB_KEY YOUR_COG_SVC_REGION YOUR_VOICE_NAME
[INFO] Avatar configuration: YOUR_AVATAR_CHARACTER YOUR_AVATAR_STYLE YOUR_AVATAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR
[INFO] Fetching ICE credentials...
[INFO] ICE credentials are valid
[INFO] WebRTC connection created.
[INFO] WebRTC status: new
[INFO] WebRTC status: checking
[INFO] WebRTC status: connected
[INFO] Connected to Azure Avatar service
[INFO] [2024-08-01T12:34:56.789Z] Avatar started.


i don't know why but the same code worked later on...don't know the reason but it worked...Thanks for help

@HamzaKhan I'm glad to know the issue was resolved.
